# How did you extend your Assert class

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tdd, assertions

I love to Extend my Assert.AreEqual to many different classes, the known one is the CollectionAssert of course, but I can think of some more such as: [ImageAssert](http://www.human-debugger.net/blog/2008/12/21/TddExtendingAssertToSupportImages.aspx), XmlAssert etc..

Did you Create your own Assert classes? and what kind of new would you like to create?

Comment: If someone finds this because they're looking for HOW (officially, by-design) to extend MSTest Assert: https://github.com/Microsoft/testfx-docs/blob/master/RFCs/002-Framework-Extensibility-Custom-Assertions.md You're welcome! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just added an implementation to [ImageAssert](https://web.archive.org/web/20131031051646/http://human-debugger.net/wp-blog/2008/12/21/tdd-extending-assert-to-support-images/) as I wrote above (in my question)
I would be glad to hear more of that kind of samples

```
[TestMethod]
public void CompareImagesSize()
{
 Image expected = Bitmap.FromFile(@"C:\ShaniData\Projects2008\TddSamples\Output\ExpectedImage.png");
 Image actual = Bitmap.FromFile(@"C:\ShaniData\Projects2008\TddSamples\Output\RhinoDiagram.png");

 Bitmap expectedBitmap = new Bitmap(expected);
 Bitmap actualBitmap = new Bitmap(actual);

 ImageAssert.HasTheSameSize(expectedBitmap, actualBitmap);
}

[TestMethod]
public void CompareTwoSameImagesButWithDifferenExtension()
{
 Image expected = Bitmap.FromFile(@"C:\ShaniData\Projects2008\TddSamples\Output\Image2.png");
 Image actual = Bitmap.FromFile(@"C:\ShaniData\Projects2008\TddSamples\Output\Image1.jpg");

 Bitmap expectedBitmap = new Bitmap(expected);
 Bitmap actualBitmap = new Bitmap(actual);

 ImageAssert.AreEqual(expectedBitmap, actualBitmap);
}

public class ImageAssert
{
    //public static void MoreMethods(Bitmap expected, Bitmap actual)
    //{
    //    //Compare image extensions
    //    //Compare Thumbnail...
    //}

    public static void HasTheSameSize(Bitmap expected, Bitmap actual)
    {
        if ((expected.Height != actual.Height)
            || (expected.Width != actual.Width))
            HandleFail("ImageAssert.HasTheSameSize", String.Empty);
    }

    public static void AreEqual(Bitmap expected, Bitmap actual)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < expected.Width; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < expected.Height; j++)
            {
                Color expectedBit = expected.GetPixel(i, j);
                Color actualBit = actual.GetPixel(i, j);
                if (!expectedBit.Equals(actualBit))
                {
                    HandleFail("ImageAssert.AreEqual", String.Empty, i, j);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    internal static void HandleFail(string assertionName, string message, params object[] parameters)
    {
        throw new AssertFailedException(String.Format(assertionName));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

That's my solution:

```
using MyStuff;

using A = Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.Assert;

namespace Mytestproj.Tests
{
    public static class Assert
    {
        public static void AreEqual(object expected, object actual)
        {
            A.AreEqual(expected, actual);
        }

        // my extension
        public static void AreEqual(MyEnum expected, int actual)
        {
            A.AreEqual((int)expected, actual);
        }

        public static void IsTrue(bool o)
        {
            A.IsTrue(o);
        }

        public static void IsFalse(bool o)
        {
            A.IsFalse(o);
        }

        public static void AreNotEqual(object notExpected, object actual)
        {
            A.AreNotEqual(notExpected, actual);
        }

        public static void IsNotNull(object o)
        {
            A.IsNotNull(o);
        }

        public static void IsNull(object o)
        {
            A.IsNull(o);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I like the feel of the Assert class, but wanted something that would serve more as a general validation framework.  I started with Roger Alsing's [article](http://rogeralsing.com/2008/05/10/followup-how-to-validate-a-methods-arguments/) on using extension methods, and now have a system that works like:

```
Enforce.That(variable).IsNotNull();
Enforce.That(variable).IsInRange(10, 20);
Enforce.That(variable).IsTypeOf(typeof(System.String));
etc.
```

If any enforcement fails, it throws an exception.  I have been considering refactoring so that I can also incorporate a non-critical evaluation that does not throw an exception.  Some like Check.That as a variant of Enforce.That which would return booleans, but have extension methods with identical signatures.

What I like about this approach, so far, is that I can use these in my unit tests, as well as for pre-validation and post-validation concerns in my actual code without referencing the Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework assembly.  I put it in my root assembly for my application framework, and Enforce is at the root, so it is very easy to get to.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of my tests revolve around loading a object that (like a CuttingPath) with a known good state.. Performing the test, then comparing the result to the loaded object. If they differ then somehthing 'happened' to cause a change in the code.

This approach save tons of time and allow for custom comparisons when needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you're refactoring your tests to reduce duplication then you end up creating your own framework as a by-product, and of course your test framework will have assert helpers that make sense in your context.

An example I have in mind was when testing xhtml report we ended up with tests that looked something like:

```
  assertCoverageEquals(45.5);
```

where behind assert coverage was something like:

```
  assertPercentage(COVERAGE_ID, 45.5);
```

and then behind that was something that used xpath to get the value and another method that knew what the formatting was for percentages.